# Method for screen sharing of one window only

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, wayland, screencast, chromecast

Back in 2019 I was using a chromecast feature available only (I believe) to linux users that allowed me to screen share just one application to a chromecast device. This solved a huge problem for me of sharing something from my screen with NO risk of private information being exposed by a pop-up notification or something from another application. An additional benefit of this sharing method was being able to match the window dimensions to the 16:9 ratio of the output display, which is different from the laptop I use. No ugly black bars!

During 2020 I wasn't using this feature due to a change in the work I was doing... now I'm back to needing it again. But today I discover that the chrome browser is no longer offering this option - just a full screen share, same as windows users have always been limited to.

So right now I'm looking for options that would allow me to re-create this functionality. Preferably I'm after something that works with Wayland (the previous method I was using never worked with Wayland).

I'm thinking there must be some linux tool that exists out there that can direct the output of a chosen window to a WebRTC stream, and then hack some way to tell my chromecast to grab that stream? But I'm open to other ideas INCLUDING connecting an HDMI cable to my second display. However, if I do that my requirement is that the second display CLONES only a window or part of my primary display to the second display - simply cloning the entire screen to another display is a privacy nightmare.

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that chromium still supports casting a single application window. In Wayland this is somewhat limited - only certain application windows are listed to be selected. I'm not sure what determines what can be cast. Terminal windows can't, but xournal - which is what I'm mainly after - does work.